# When is a six-dimensional manifold the twistor space of a four-dimensional manifold?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

What are the conditions on a six-dimensional manifold to be the twistor space of a four-dimensional one?

Comment: Is the 4-dimensional manifold simply Riemannian or does it have more structure (hyperKahler, quaternionic-Kahler)? Are there any compactness assumptions?

Comment: Maybe the question is about the manifolds diffeomorphic to the sphere bundle of the vector bundle of self-dual two-forms of some oriented riemannian 4-manifold ?

Comment: The question is more about the six-dimensional manifold. Take some 6-dimensional manifold (say for example nearly Kaehler), when is it the twistor space of a four-dimensional manifold? Is the four-dimensional manifold then quaternionic Kaehler for example?

Comment: @Malopa:  Are you assuming that the $6$-manifold is endowed with more structure than just being a smooth manifold?  Are you assuming, for example, that it's endowed with a given almost complex structure and metric and you want to know whether they arise as the ones associated to a twistor space of a Riemannian $4$-manifold?  Otherwise, your question is a bit vague.

Comment: The OP hasn't logged on for nearly five years so don't expect clarification anytime soon...

Comment: @PaulReynolds:  Good point.  I was fooled by the question coming up near the top of the list this morning when I logged on.  I didn't check the dates, as I should have.  I wonder what caused it to surface again?

Comment: @RobertBryant: I believe it was my answer which was added 11 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ be the twistor space of a four-manifold $M$. The six-manifold $Z$ can be equipped with an almost complex structure. Furthermore, Hitchin showed that $Z$ is in fact spin.

This may look like two separate conditions for $Z$ to be a twistor space, but in fact the second implies the first as a six-manifold admits an almost complex structure if and only if it admits a spin$^c$ structure.

Comment: I think OP was asking for necessary and sufficient conditions rather than just necessary conditions.